# consuming a rest api inside Express: userid not found

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, request

Insprirated on [Gettin MEAN](https://www.manning.com/books/getting-mean-with-mongo-express-angular-and-node) I am making my own application. I try to connect to front end to the backend in Express. I copied the text but my console.log still giving me the message 'userid not found'. I think I am pretty close to the finish. Any tips or helpful links are appreciated.

1. the Usermodel

```html
const userSchema = new Schema({

    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    userName: String,
    telephone: String,
    password: String
    
});
```

2. the route in the api

```html
router
    .route('/users/:userid')
    .get(ctrlUsers.userReadOne);
    
module.exports = router;
```

In Postman this get.request works (for example)

```html
http://localhost:3000/api/users/5ad87da47bb05b0594fff5b6
```

Together with the book I programmed the app/server/controller:

route:

```html
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const ctrlUsers = require('../controllers/users');

router.get('/users/:userid', ctrlUsers.userInfo);

module.exports = router;
```

and the controllers. Here my console.log gives 'no userid found'

```html
const request = require('request');
const apiOptions = {
    server: 'http://localhost:3000'
};
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    apiOptions.server = 'https://pure-temple-67771.herokuapp.com';
}



/*Get myprofile */
const userInfo = function (req, res) {
    const path = '/api/users/${req.params.userid}';
    requestOptions = {
        url: apiOptions.server + path,
        method: 'GET',
        json: {}
    };

    console.log('path  ' + requestOptions.url);

    request(
        requestOptions,
        (err, response, body) => {
            _rendermyProfile(req, res, body);
            console.log(body); // no userid found 
            });
};




const _rendermyProfile = function (req, res, userDetail) {
    res.render('myProfile', {
        profile: {
            title: 'Mijn profiel',
            firstName: userDetail.firstName,
            lastName: userDetail.lastName,
            email: userDetail.email,
            telephone: userDetail.telephone
        }
    });
};






module.exports = {
    userInfo
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you will get no userid found, because you have a misusage of string literal. Inside your controller, changed from this:

```
const path = '/api/users/${req.params.userid}';
```

to this:

```
const path = `/api/users/${req.params.userid}`;
```

String literal is only working if you used a back slash **`**.

Now your App should make a request correctly.

Comment: that helped me a lot

Comment: Answer useful +1, my repu <15 marked but not visible